# $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-2x^Tx}= \left(\sum_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2y^2}\right)^n$ is true?

Tags: summation

Is the following true?

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-2x^Tx}= \left(\sum_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2y^2}\right)^n\;?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Note that right side sums converge absolutely, so rearrangement is OK.  Write the right side as $$\sum_{x_1 = -\infty}^\infty \ldots \sum_{x_n = -\infty}^\infty \exp(-2 x_1^2) \ldots \exp(-2 x_n^2)
= \sum_{x_1 = -\infty}^\infty \ldots \sum_{x_n = -\infty}^\infty \exp(-2 (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2))$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll prove this for the case $n=2$, from where it is obvious for the case of arbitrary $n$.

$$\sum\limits_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^2}e^{-2x^Tx} = \sum\limits_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-2(i^2+j^2)}=\sum\limits_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-2i^2}e^{-2j^2}=\left(\sum\limits_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-2i^2}\right)\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-2j^2}\right)=\left(\sum\limits_{y\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-2y^2}\right)^2$$